# Socket.io AngularJS Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: angularjs, get, socket.io, chat, http-status-code-403

I have an App on AngularJS but when I try to integrate Socket.io to a Chat, it gave me a problem... so here it is:

```
GET http://localhost:2772/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1433165408651-0 403 (Forbidden)
```

Its on `socket.io-1.3.5.js` library

An the principal error its here

```
xhr.send(this.data)}catch(e){...
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a library left..

on HTML:
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-socket-io/mock/socket-io.js"></script>`